# VS 2017 / ASP.net - Global functions not being recognized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, global-variables, visual-studio-2017

I made the jump from VS 2010 (VB) all the way to VS 2017, and that may have been a mistake. I've already been slowed down with bugs, which I have reported. My latest concern is about accessing a global functions class that I have never had a problem with in VS 2010. I have reported it and it is in triage, but I wanted to make sure that something hasn't changed in the versions since 2010, hoping someone here can tell me.

Essentially what happens is that the global class, no matter how it is configured, is not recognized by any other class. Including a reference in a form class causes the IDE to tag it as an error. For example, the code in the GlobalFunctions.vb document:

```
Public Class GlobalFunctions

    Public Function DecodeBase64(strEncoded As String) As String
        Dim byt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(strEncoded)
        Return (System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byt))
    End Function

    Public Function EncodeBase64(strUnencoded As String) As String
        Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strUnencoded)
        Return (Convert.ToBase64String(byt))
    End Function
End Class
```

and the calling methods from a form page:

```
If elemSetting.Attributes("name").Value = "LoginName" Then
    Session("MailLoginName") = globalfunctions.DecodeBase64(elemSetting.Attributes("value").Value)
End If

If elemSetting.Attributes("name").Value = "LoginPass" Then
    Session("MailLoginPass") = globalfunctions.DecodeBase64(elemSetting.Attributes("value").Value)
End If
```

Here the errors are being highlighted in the IDE:

[image: IDE Errors]

And the error messages in the error list:

[image: Error list]

Understand, too, that I have tried as many variations of declarations as I can think of, such as "Public Shared Function," making the calling sub Shared, defining the global functions document as a Class or a Module, etc. Nothing works.

I've also tried placing the GlobalFunctions.vb class in the project's root directory and in a directory named `App_Code`, as was suggested in some blog posts around the net.

And since I have had no trouble like this with VS 2010, I assume it's a bug in 2017, which, as I said, I have reported. But I wanted to check with better minds than my own to see if I have overlooked something that may have changed somewhere between 2010 and 2017.

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong? Or maybe reaffirm for me that this is, indeed, a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: First GlobalFunction is a Class and not an instance of that class. So to call directly those methods using the class name they should be marked as _Shared_

Comment: Second. Is the Class GlobalFunctions in a different project? If yes do you have checked if the appropriate reference has been made and the correct Imports are in place? If no does the page and the class use the same namespace (and again check the Imports) ?

Comment: @Steve I think it's just he didn't create an instance of his class. And yeah totally agree with shared

Comment: @Mederic the error message is clear. From the point of view of the page code there is no class named GlobalFunctions. Something is missing here

Comment: @Steve as I mentioned, I tried several methods for declaring the functions and the Class/Module, including "Shared," Public," etc. I just haven't shown them all here because it would clutter up the message.

Comment: It is not that the problem (or at least not only that). I have asked some clarification in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete and recreate your `GlobalFunction.vb` as maybe by renaming it in the past it didn't correctly correct everywhere in the project.

I think this is normal. You are using a `Class` and not a `Module` so you would need to declare a new instance either call like this:

```
Dim Globaler As New GlobalFunctions
If elemSetting.Attributes("name").Value = "LoginName" Then
    Session("MailLoginName") = Globaler.DecodeBase64(elemSetting.Attributes("value").Value)
End If
If elemSetting.Attributes("name").Value = "LoginPass" Then
    Session("MailLoginPass") = Globaler.DecodeBase64(elemSetting.Attributes("value").Value)
End If
```

Or use a Module and you wont need to declare a new instance.

**Also if it still can't be accessed you should check the fact that maybe you just included the file to the solution without including it to the project**

To Add new class:

- Solution Explorer
- Right Click your Project Name (above My Project)
- Add
- Class

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I tried doing this also as a module, which is how I had done it in 2010 without trouble. I used Class here because it seemed to be recommended more prevalently in blogs.

Comment: Sure Class and Module differentiate and both have their advantage in a way But i would recommend Classes when you have to store data for creating your own objects.

Comment: The problem here is the fact that the code in the Page cannot see a class named GlobalFunctions. Your code doesn't change this.

Comment: @Mederic (Update) I tried as you suggested, and the IDE shows an error that "Type 'GlobalFunctions' is not defined."

Comment: @Steve true i was solving next step problem my bad

Comment: @BillNorman Make sure you added the class to the project and not just as file in solution

Comment: @Mederic Following steps in various blog posts, I right-clicked the Solution name, selected Add > New Item > Class (or Module). Is that sufficient?

Comment: Dont right Click the solution Name but right click the Project Name (just above myproject) and Add from there

Comment: @Mederic My bad, I should have said Project name. That's where I right-clicked. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143797/discussion-between-mederic-and-bill-norman).

Comment: @Mederic Thanks for your patience, bud! That worked! Like I said in chat, I can't imagine how it got screwed up, but it must have, because it's all good now. Thanks again!